# Unable to access the XML tag value using Karate.get() method

Tags: karate

Unable to access the XML tag value using Karate.get() method

```
* def xml1 =
      """
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
  <ns2:QueryUsageBalance xmlns:ns2="http://www.mycompany.com/usage/V1">
      <ns2:UsageBalance>
          <ns2:LicenseId>12341234</ns2:LicenseId>
      </ns2:UsageBalance>
  </ns2:QueryUsageBalance>
  </S:Body>
  </S:Envelope>
  """
    * def temp1 = karate.get('$xml1/S:Envelope/S:Body/ns2:QueryUsageBalance/ns2:UsageBalance/ns2:LicenseId')
    * def result1 = temp1 ? 'yes' : 'no'
   * print temp1
```

It's printing "no", seems unable to identify the XPATH. Could anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Hi Peter, i am unable to find the check mark against the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: no idea, others are able to do it - so try again

Comment: Finally, I marked the answer of my previous question as "accepted" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you spend more time reading the docs and [examples](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature).

```
* def temp1 = $xml1/Envelope/Body/QueryUsageBalance/UsageBalance/LicenseId
* match temp1 == '12341234'
```